# how copy table storage tables to other table storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

I want to move my old blob storage (with tables) to a new location:

I found how I can move blobs to a new account.

```
azcopy copy "https://<source-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-path>?<SAS-token>" "https://<destination-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-path>"
```

and it's work fine for me, but I need to copy all my tables to new account too.

I found only how I can copy one table to a new account. 
But I have a lot of tables and can be a problem for me copy one-by-one.

Does Azure have similar commands for copying Azure table storage tables to other blog storage?

I try to use azcopy copy with `https://<destination-storage-account-name>.**table**.core.windows.net...` 
but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AzCopy v10 doesn't support Azure Table Storage unfortunately. To export/import data from/to Azure Table Storage, you need to use [AzCopy v8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#export-data-from-table-storage) instead. Note that it doesn't support direct Table to Table copy, so you need to export the source table to local disk or Blob Storage at first, then import it to another destination table.

Comment: but I need to copy table per table, can i copy all tables to disk or block and export it to new azure storage account?

Comment: No, you have to write a PowerShell or Azure CLI script to list tables within a storage account and invoke AzCopy one table after another.

Comment: hm, so Microsoft doesn't have any solutions for copy Azure table storage (blob) to another location? =/

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a solution for this problem, please look at a package I released on NuGet  [AzureTableUtilities](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TheByteStuff.AzureTableUtilities/)

You can copy a table to another table on the same account or a different account.

Answer (score 0):

IF the destination is a paired region, you could just use a GRS or a RA-GRS storage account.  That would take care of a lot of the nuances and consistency issues for you.

For one of our clients, I created this janky little demo which shows it takes about 8 seconds for the RA-GRS storage account, East US 2 to Central, to become consistent.

https://github.com/raycrawford/azure_ragrs_table_demo